# Issue implementing "More or less" game

Tags: java

So it seems like I have read all the posts and it just doesn't seem to work like I would like it to work? The code is supposed to check whether the number you input is the one given by RNG. Once the answer is correct I would like it to start over? Thank you guys!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
import java.util.Random;

public class crs {

    private static Scanner in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randno = rand.nextInt(100)+1; 
        int dig = 0;

    do {
            System.out.println("Number generated. Try your luck!: ");

        dig = 0;


         randno = rand.nextInt(100)+1; 
        //nextInt(int n) Returns a random integer value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive),
         while (dig!=randno) {

         in = new Scanner(System.in);
         dig = in.nextInt();    

    if (dig<randno) {
        System.out.println("Too low!");
    }else if (dig>randno) {
        System.out.println("Too high!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Correct!");

    }}}

    while(dig!=randno); 

    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was a bit messy and the second loop was useless. I think this version should works better.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randno = rand.nextInt(100)+1; 
    int dig;

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Number generated. Try your luck!: ");

        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        dig = in.nextInt();    

        if (dig<randno)
        {
            System.out.println("Too low!");
        }
        else if (dig>randno)
        {
            System.out.println("Too high!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried to use it and it seems to give out an answer of :

Number generated. Try your luck!: 
8
Correct!

But doesn't start the program again? Additionally it prints out "Number generated" with each line. Overall however  - thanks for tidying the code. I am still learning and this is highly appreciated. Seems so much easier to read now.

Comment: @PatrykSarnik For running the game forever you just need to add an infinite loop around all this code. And for "Number generated" you can just print a bit earlier, I'm sure you will figure it out.

Comment: @PatrykSarnik And don't forget to validate an answer if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just put another while loop arround:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randno, dig = 0;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Number generated. Try your luck!: ");

        randno = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        while (dig != randno) {
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            dig = in.nextInt();
            if (dig < randno) {
                System.out.println("Too low!");
            } else if (dig > randno) {
                System.out.println("Too high!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also created the random number twice and had an unnecessary second loop.